# Site going down, while indexing

Tags: magento-1.9

I have more than **20** thousand products in my website. Whenever i **reindex** the Product flat data, Catalog **URL** rewrite it taking too much time and suddenly the site going down. After i have to restart the database server to bring the site to live.

I tried **reindexing** the data's using terminal also throwing error
**`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away`**

Comment: check server ram and configuration, did you enabled flat catalog and product?

Comment: I dont have much knowledge in server. As i known when i reindex the data the RAM taking whole memory.

Comment: ok, please ask your server provider to increase RAM. you can learn how to enable flat from here : https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat-setup.html

Comment: The Flat catalog is already enabled bro. I'll ask my server provider to increase the RAM. Thanks

Comment: @satya Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop, top & mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
free -h          for memory sizes
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @satya In your journey to become a professional Magento developer, please provide the information requested July 12, 2018 and you will receive suggestions to improve your MySQL instance performance that work 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.  Happy Holidays.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Okay Sure

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly due to any of the below two reasons

- Server timed out and closed the connection.

  **Fix:** Try increasing the wait_timeout variable in your mysqld’s my.cnf/my.ini configuration file.
- Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet.

  **Fix :** increase the maximal packet size limit by increasing the value of max_allowed_packet in my.cnf/my.ini file.
- Change this configuration to up of according to of server capacity

  **a)** key_buffer **b)** thread_stack **c)** thread_cache_size **d)** innodb_buffer_pool_size

Try this for fix

Comment: Hello Rahul. thanks for the reply. I increased "wait_timeout" and "max_allowed_packet" sizes already but still not worked. I'll try the third one..

Comment: ok, all the best

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # to avoid thread starved server
```

this might be only one of the critical GLOBAL SYSTEM VARIABLES.

Please view my profile, Network Profile for contact information.

Comment: @satya Has this helped?

Comment: Hello @Wilson Thanks for your reply. I tried all these. But no luck. I installed one module 'Patch indexurl' it started working.

Comment: @satya My offer of Jul 12, 2018 is still valid if you could post the additional information requested from your system.  Glad you are working now.

Comment: @satya  If you could post on pastebin.com or here,  Text results of: A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  I would be able to provide meaningful suggestions for your consideration.